# Install Gnome on top of KDE

Tags: debian, installation, gnome, kde, debian-stretch

I am running Debian 9 (stretch) with KDE Plasma 5.8.6 and I am having some issues with Plasma. Can I, on top of KDE install Gnome DE and then delete KDE? 
A beginners question: If I can do it, then my programs/files will be unaffected right?

Comment: You can install any desktop environment you want, and boot from it instead of the one that came with your distro. You'll have to install lots of dependencies, though, so the upgrade will take some time. There might be some instabilities, too, due to possible conflicts between graphics settings, but nothing to worry about. Proceed as explained here and you should be fine: https://linuxhint.com/install_gnome_debian_10_minimal_server/

Comment: @Didier Thank you. What kind of instabilities are you referring to? Also, in the link that you gave, the commands are run in the terminal in an ordinary session or do I have to use some specific tty?

Comment: Plasma/KDE and Gnome don't work exactly the same way when it comes to "paint" your desktop and windows, and other content, on your PC screen, so installing a new desktop environment usually means installing new video drivers, and it may take some time before you feel comfortable with the way things look in Gnome, compared to KDE's eye-candy. The commands require a "sudo" prefix, which means they are performed as admin. You'll have to enter your admin password after the 1st command (sudo remains active for several minutes while you're in a Terminal session). The cursor won't move while you type

Comment: @Didier yeah I know these things. You didn't answer though if I can do it in a normal session or I have to do it from a specific tty? Also what about my programs and my files? Do they remain unchanged? Thank you

Comment: Your personal files will remain untouched. What may change is the default applications that are DE(Desktop Environment)-specific, such as your file explorer, video player, etc... But you can install whatever hits your fancy afterwards. I don't understand what you mean by "normal session", but all you have to do is fire up a Terminal right from KDE, enter the commands mentioned in the link I supplied you, reboot after updating, install Gnome, reboot after installing it, and at first logon, choose which DE you want to boot on, then you're good to go.